# What happens to the previous Oracle session after giving CONNECT statement?

Tags: oracle, session, object

Say, User a connects to Oracle, gives command CONNECT b/bpassword.
Please advise,  "What happens to the previous Oracle session and its objects after giving CONNECT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve015.htm#SQPUG036) states

> **Usage**
>
> CONNECT commits the current transaction to the database, disconnects the current username from Oracle Database, and reconnects with the specified username.

Answer (score 0):

The session will be in closed or in idle state as demonstrated here:

```
select sid, serial#, username from v$session where username is not null and status = 'ACTIVE' order by sid
SQL> /

       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
       14   50651 DBSNMP
       320  24195 SYSMAN
       326  24103 SYS

SQL> conn ptuning/ptuning
Connected.
SQL> /

       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
       14   50651 DBSNMP
       320  24195 SYSMAN
       485   3723 PTUNING

SQL>
```

Below query shows that session is closed in this case.

```
SQL> select sid, serial#, username, status from v$session where sid=326;

no rows selected

SQL>
```